# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'question_id' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

I am trying to persist the Question data along with answers in Mysql using Spring .
In my case Question is a parent and Answer is a child and answer contains the options including correct ones.
I have used one to many mapping in the classes. When i persisted these data , i notice Question(Parent) is persisted without any issue but not Answer entity.
I tried many ways but no luck. I appreciate your help.

Here is my child class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="answer")
public class Answer extends AuditModel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@NotBlank
private String qoption;

private String isCorrect;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "question_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Question question; 
// and setters and getters for these
```

Below is my parent class

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="question")
 public class Question extends AuditModel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@NotBlank
private String description;

@NotBlank
private String qcategory;

@NotNull
@NotBlank
private String qtype;

private String lsaQuestion;

private String clue;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "question")
private List<Answer> answers;
// and setters and getters for these
```

and below code for data mapping

```
     private QuestionDto createDTOObject(QuestionRequest request, String questionImageUrl, String 
     clueImageUrl, String addinfoimageUrl) {

    QuestionDto question=new QuestionDto();
    question.setDescription(request.getDescription());
    question.setClueImageUrl(clueImageUrl);
    question.setAddinfoimageUrl(addinfoimageUrl);
    question.setExplImageUrl(explImageUrl);
    List<AnswerDto> answers = mapAnswers(request,question);
    question.setAnswers(answers);

    return question;
}

/**
 * @param request
 * @return
 */
private List<AnswerDto> mapAnswers(QuestionRequest request,QuestionDto question) {
    List<AnswerDto> answers = new ArrayList<AnswerDto>();
    for (AnswerDto ad : request.getAnswers()) {
        AnswerDto dto = new AnswerDto();
        dto.setQoption(ad.getQoption());
        dto.setIsCorrect(ad.getIsCorrect());
        answers.add(dto);
    }
    return answers;
}
```

and the below code for persisting both objects in Impl class using Spring Data JPA

```
 @Override
public String create(QuestionDto dto) {
    Question model = mapper.toModel(dto);   
    quizRepository.save(model);
    return model.getId().toString();
}
```

I have a Answer DTO as below

```
public class AnswerDto {

private String qoption;

private String isCorrect;

private QuestionDto question; 

public QuestionDto getQuestion() {
    return question;
}
public void setQuestion(QuestionDto question) {
    this.question = question;
}
```

I have Question DTO as follows..

```
public class QuestionDto {

private List<AnswerDto> answers;

    public List<AnswerDto> getAnswers() {
    return answers;
}

public void setAnswers(List<AnswerDto> answers) {
    this.answers = answers;
}
```

I have Question (Model) as follows as i posted above in previous

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "question")
private List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();
```

I have Answer (Model) as below.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "question_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Question question; 

public Question getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(Question question) {
    this.question = question;
}
```

So i convert my json request to Question DTO and adding Answer DTO to Question DTO as bidirectional mapping needed as you mentioned. 
While persisting we are converting that Question DTO to Question (Model) using below code.

```
@Autowired
private QuizMapper mapper;

@Override
public String create(QuestionDto dto) {
    Question model = mapper.toModel(dto);   
    quizRepository.save(model);
    return model.getId().toString();
}
```

while converting the DTO to Model i am getting Stack overflow error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined a bidirectional relationship, you have to set the relation in both `Answer` and `Question` entities:

```java
    question.setAnswers(answers);
    for (var a : answers) {
        a.setQuestion(question);
    }
```

Edit:

> So i convert my json request to Question DTO and adding Answer DTO to Question DTO as bidirectional mapping needed as you mentioned

I think you are mixing things up here. You are using bidirectional association in your Models (entities), meaning that your child entity stores a reference to its parent and the parent entity stores references to all of its children. In the DTOs, obviously, you don't need to have a reference back to the `Question` from the `Answer` DTO. What you are supposed to do, briefly:

- map JSON to DTO
- map DTO to Entity

  - set the `Question` entity in each `Answer`
  - add the answers to the `answers` list in your `Question` model
- save the `Question` entity, since you use `CascadeType.PERSIST` it should cascade the `persist` operation to each new `Answer` entity as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Krisz,Thank you for the reply and i tried that i am getting below error while mapping the DTO to model class.                                                     
  java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at com.alprep.alprep.elearning.quiz.mapper.QuizMapperImpl.answerDtoToAnswer(QuizMapperImpl.java:81) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.alprep.alprep.elearning.quiz.mapper.QuizMapperImpl.answerDtoListToAnswerList(QuizMapperImpl.java:101) ~[classes/:na]
            at com.alprep.alprep.elearning.quiz.mapper.QuizMapperImpl.answerDtoToAnswer(QuizMapperImpl.java:87) ~[classes/:na]

Comment: It's a `StackOverflowError`, meaning you have an infinite loop somewhere in your code. Can you edit your question with how the `setQuestion` and `setAnswers` methods are implemented?

Comment: Hi Krisz,i have just updated the question. Please check.

Comment: I have removed the DTO's and captured the request directly to Model object and its working as expected.